# Why mybatis insert java.util.Date value to Mysql datetime column then fetch it they are not equal?

Tags: datetime, mybatis, mysql-connector

Mybatis insert java.util.Date to mysql datetime column, then fetch it find they are not match

Table

```
CREATE TABLE `t` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`create_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

code

```
@Insert("insert into t(create_time) values(#{0})")
int insertT(Date date);
@Select("select create_time from t order by id desc limit 1")
Date getLatestCreateTime();
```

Unit test

```
    Date date1 = new Date();
    mapper.insertT(date1);

    Date date2 = mapper.getLatestCreateTime();

    Assert.assertEquals(date1, date2);
```

Assert fail

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :Tue Aug 02 22:10:35 CST 2016
Actual   :Tue Aug 02 22:10:36 CST 2016
```

why is so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because when `TimeUtil` in `mysql-connector` convert Timstamp to Date, it executes below code

```
    Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(tsAsMillis1 + (long)offsetDiff);
    ts.setNanos(secondsPart);
```

and `secondsPart` is 0.

```
@Test
public void test_date_compare_date_from_timestamp() {
    Date date1 = new Date();

    Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(date1.getTime());
    System.out.println(ts);  // 2016-08-08 22:37:37.078
    Date date2 = new Date(ts.getTime());
    Assert.assertEquals(date1, date2);
    ts.setNanos(0);
    System.out.println(ts); // 2016-08-08 22:37:37.0
    Date date3 = new Date(ts.getTime());
    Assert.assertNotEquals(date1, date3);
}
```

and as for the seconds is more then original seconds, it is because

```
insert into t select 1,'2016-08-08 22:42:44.676';
select * from t;
+----+---------------------+
| id | create_time         |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | 2016-08-08 22:42:45 |
+----+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I was using this mysql table:- (Ignore the object/class names.)

```
CREATE TABLE `user_access` (
`user_id` INT NOT NULL,
`access_datetime` DATETIME NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (user_id)  REFERENCES users (user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

And the controller makes this call to the mybatis mapper.

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Date;

cardsMapper.updateUserAccess(user.getEmail(), new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
```

And the mapper interface has the foolowing code:-

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
@Insert("INSERT INTO user_access VALUES ( (select user_id from users where email = #{email}) , #{dateValue} )")
void updateUserAccess(String email, Timestamp dateValue);
```

---

And when the code ran, the table got both the date and time stored in the access_datetime column.

Hope this helps somebody.
Thanks